# React native scrollview not scrolling when keyboard pops up

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I would like to scroll to other inputs when the keyboard pops up. It works fine on iOS but not android - any ideas?

```
 <View style={positions.fullHeight}>
    <ScrollView style={common.scrollView} >
        <SubHeader title={registrationLabels.pleaseTryAgainTitle} />
        <View style={common.textCenter}>
          ...
          </Text>
        </View>
        <FormWrapper>
          <Controller
              as={(
                <InputField
                keyboardType="numeric"
                  {...AccessibilityHelper('Please try again membership number field')}
                errorMessage={errors.membershipNumber && errors.membershipNumber.message}
                />
              )}
              ...
          />
          <Controller
            as={(
              <InputField
                   {...AccessibilityHelper('Please try again first name field')}
                errorMessage={errors.firstName && errors.firstName.message}
              />
            )}
            ...
          />
          <Controller
            as={(
              <InputField
                errorMessage={errors.lastName && errors.lastName.message}
              />
            )}
            ...
          />
          <Controller
            as={(
              <InputField
                   {...AccessibilityHelper('Please try again postcode field')}
                errorMessage={errors.postcode && errors.postcode.message}
              />
            )}
            ...
          />
        </FormWrapper>
    </ScrollView>
    <View style={positions.buttonContainer}>
      <Button
          title={registrationLabels.buttonConfirm}
          onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
          disabled={isDisabled}
          accessibilityHelperId="Continue Button"
          skipDebounce={false}
      />
    </View>

  </View>
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide the full code with imports and styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change top `View` to `KeyboardAvoidingView`
i,e

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={positions.fullHeight} behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
    children
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

You can import `KeyboardAvoidingView` from `react-native`